# Reactive programming with REScala

Tags: scala

In the official [manual](http://guidosalva.github.io/REScala/manual/) of RESCALA, the modifier `val` is used instead of `var` for declaring Vars. I am wondering why since we are talking about variables and not immutable constants?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to track changes of Scala `var` which is required for the FRP to work. Thus custom container class `Var[T]` is used to store variables. This container can track changes of the value inside. But once you have to use container for a variable, it doesn't make any sense to make the container itself a variable. Moreover it makes much more sense to make them read-only (i.e. `val`) because when your `Signal` tracks dependency, it is tracked to the specific `Var` object rather than to specific field or variable.

In other words, it is very hard to make code like this work in FRP-style (probably impossible without some pre- or post-compilation)

```
val SPEED = 10
var time = 0
var space = Signal{ SPEED * time }
space.changed += ((x: Int) => println(x))
time = time + 1
```

but it is relatively easy to make the example from the manual work (notice how to read or set value of `time` accessor `time()` is used)

```
val SPEED = 10
val time = Var(0)
val space = Signal{ SPEED * time() }
space.changed += ((x: Int) => println(x))
time() = time.now + 1
```